# Piping not working within bash script when run from a GUI as opposed to bash shell

Tags: xcode, bash, piping

As part of my build process I'm trying to mount a DMG using `hdiutil`.

I've written a shell script to do this, and because `hdiutil` asks for confirmation of the license agreement before opening, I have in my script something like `yes | hdiutil ...`. When I run the script from a bash shell like Terminal.app there are no problems and the process works as expected.

However, when I add an 'external build system' target to Xcode and have /bin/bash run my script, it hangs forever after executing the `hdiutil` command.

I'm guessing that `yes` is not terminating; what would cause this to behave differently when the script is invoked by a GUI app as opposed to an interactive bash shell and how can I make it work using both approaches?

Comment: `yes` should die when it receives `SIGPIPE`. I have no way of testing this. Some (stupid) programs decide to make themselves difficult by reading from `/dev/tty` directly and bypassing stdin. Use `lsof` or whatever system call tracer is available on your system to determine where it's actually reading from. If that's the problem, you'll have to use `expect` or another language that you can connect to a pty through such as Python's `pty.spawn()` to automate this.

Comment: Surely you mean `echo y | hdiutil`?  Why would you want this to be repetitive?

Comment: Yes, `echo y | hdiutil` works fine. Repeat your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `echo y | hdiutil` isntead of `yes | hdiutil` as suggested by @trojanfoe.